# Can SVG images be used?

Tags: actions-on-google, api-ai

For some reason, I can't get SVG images to show up on my phone, only the simulator. Is this bug / feature that is in progress / expected? I can't find any documentation on file formats in the [guide](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/Image).

Don't know if this affects it, but I'm using API.AI's Actions on Google tab to create the carousel.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phone doesn't support SVG, and that's the expected behavior.
You can use JPG, PNG or even GIF with animations.

I agree that this should be available in the documentation.